# RxJava Collect emission to list

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2, rx-kotlin

How can I collect emitted items from observable to List when observable never completes?

Example I have something similar so Observable emits series of values, but never completes unless you unsubscribe, because of that `.toList()` not gonna work.

```
Observable<User>
 .flatMap {}
 .toList()
```

How can I collect All users to List and emit it once after applying flatMap function to it?

Comment: Read here: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/wiki/Blocking-Observable-Operators

Comment: What are the conditions? I mean, when do you know you should emit the list of all users if the observer never completes?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few options here. If you want to collect them periodically you could use `buffer()`. Or if you have some other signal to collect you might use `where()`.